# Save ocean shape layer using another CRS problem using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I downloaded Natural Earth Ocean Data http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-ocean/
and tried to reproject by saving the layer as different name and CRS using QGIS

[image]

Then, it gives me weird looking shapefile:

[image]

Also, America continent and South Asia's land areas are filled.

[image]

Using ArcMap, it's totally fine.
I am just curious why it happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oceans layer extends to the North Pole and so goes to infinity when reprojected to any Mercator projection. If you clip the layer at 85N you should have no problem.

I suspect that ArcMap does this quietly behind the scenes while QGis trusts you to know what you are doing.

Comment: do you know why it has to be 85N? and there's no limit latitude to South?

Comment: there is less ocean in the south - normally you would clip at +/-85

Comment: 85 is a pragmatic choice, technically it only goes to infinity at 90 but the numbers get quite big above 85

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! it helped me a lot :) though what would be the exact coordinates to clip my layer by extent? I used -180, 180, -90, 85

Comment: in general, I would use -180,180, -85,85 but with Antarctica/oceans you could leave south pole unclipped